# In App SMS With Attachment - MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate Related Errors

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, sms, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have the following code that takes a partial snapshot of my screen in-app, then opens up a SMS dialogue window.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{


@IBAction func smsScreenShot(sender: AnyObject) {

    audioPlayer.play()

    // Declare the snapshot boundaries 
    let top: CGFloat = 100
    let bottom: CGFloat = 60

    // The size of the cropped image
    let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height - top - bottom)

    // Start the context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -top)

    // Draw the view into the context (this is the snapshot)
    view.layer.renderInContext(context)
    let snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // End the context (this is required to not leak resources)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Composing the SMS

    if !MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        print("SMS services are not available")
    }

    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {

        let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

        composeVC.recipients = ["Enter tel no"]
        composeVC.body = "Have a look at this cool image!";

        // Attaching the image to the SMS.
        let image = snapshot
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        composeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData!, typeIdentifier: "image/png", filename:"myImage")

        self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated:true, completion:nil)

    }

}
```

I realise I have to add `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` in the `class` construct just after 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate'.

In doing so, I receive the following error:

```
Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate'
```

And this is because I haven't dismissed the controller.

To dismiss the MFMMessageComposeViewController, I added the following code:

```
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

switch result.value {
case MessageComposeResultCancelled.value:
    NSLog("cancelled")
case MessageComposeResultFailed.value:
    NSLog("cancelled")
case MessageComposeResultSent.value:
    NSLog("cancelled")
default:
    NSLog("default...")
}
controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

And I inserted this code just after:

```
self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

But now I am presented with the same `Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate'` error as well as errors in the switch statement.

**Switch Statement Errors**

Firstly, I had an error using `result.value` so I changed it to `result.rawValue`. That seemed to solve that error.

But I now have errors in the `case` statements: `Value of type 'MessageComposeResult' has no member 'value'`. I think this is because the syntax surrounding `MessageComposeResult` is outdated or wrong?

How can I fix my case statements? I guess if I fix the case statements, all my problems will be resolved?

I have spent hours scouring similar questions and material on the Web, but am really stumped here.

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong? And how to amend my code?

Many thanks.

**Amended Code**

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import AVFoundation


    class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

   // Composing the SMS

    if !MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        print("SMS services are not available")
    }

    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {


        let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()


        composeVC.recipients = ["Enter tel no"]
        composeVC.body = "Have a look at this cool image!";
        composeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

        // Attaching the image to the SMS.

        let image = snapshot
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        composeVC.addAttachmentData(imageData!, typeIdentifier: "image/png", filename:"myImage")



        self.presentViewController(composeVC, animated:true, completion:nil)

        func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
            switch result {
            case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
                NSLog("Cancelled")

            case MessageComposeResultFailed:
                NSLog("Failed")

            case MessageComposeResultSent:
                NSLog("Sent")

            default:
                NSLog("Unknown result")

            }

        }
```

Comment: That warning is because you haven't implemented the required method of the delegate - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate/messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:  but you also haven't set your view controller as the MFMessageComposeViewController's delegate.

Comment: If I add `func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

switch result.value {
case MessageComposeResultCancelled.value:
    NSLog("cancelled")
case MessageComposeResultFailed.value:
    NSLog("cancelled")
case MessageComposeResultSent.value:
    NSLog("cancelled")
default:
    NSLog("default...")
}
controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}` isn't that implementing the required method?

Comment: Yes, but if that function has errors then it will be ignored. Fix the errors in the switch statement (you don't say what they are) and the function will be recognised

Comment: I have amended my question to be more clear re the switch statement. I think you're right. Fix the switch statement, and the function will work and my code should work in totality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using an `MFMessageComposeViewController` but you have said that your class is an `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` - **Message** vs **Mail**. You have implemented the delegate method for the `MFMessageComposeViewController`, which doesn't match the declaration for your class, so you get the error.

You want

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

and then

```
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch result {
    case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog("Cancelled")

    case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog("Failed")

    case MessageComposeResultSent:
        NSLog("Sent")

    default:
        NSLog("Unknown result")

    }

}
```

Also, you haven't set your view controller as the delegate, so the delegate method won't be invoked:

```
let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
composeVC.messageComposeDelegate=self
```

Comment: I have declared  `class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
` because I also have another function in my app that emails the screenshot.

Comment: I have added your amended `func messageComposeViewController ...` code, and also added `let composeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            composeVC.delegate=self` as per your instructions. But I now get an error : `Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UINavigationControllerDelegate?'` attached to the `composeVC.delegate=self` line of code.

Comment: I have added my amended code to the bottom of my initial question. Thanks very much for all assistance.

Comment: Sorry, that class has two delegates; I have updated my answer

Comment: Ahh. Yes, thats why you amended to specify `messageComposeDelegate`. Gotcha. Have amended my code accordingly, but I'm still left with the `Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate'` error.

Comment: I imported the MessageUI.framework as a linked framework. That's correct?